# Cannot invoke 'insert' with an argument list of type '([(ModelMessageBridge)], atindex: int)'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, insert

I'm trying to prepend an array with another array of messages, but I have the error :

> Cannot invoke 'insert' with an argument list of type '([(ModelMessageBridge)], atindex: int)'

Here is my code:

```
var JSQmessages = [ModelMessageBridge]()
//fill up the array here

self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({

   // indexPaths for earlier messages
   let lastIdx = history.count - 1
   var indexPaths: [AnyObject] = []
   for i in 0...lastIdx {
             indexPaths.append(NSIndexPath(forItem: i, inSection: 0))
   }

   //Convert the new messages in modelbridge
   var messages = [ModelMessageBridge]()

   for message in history {
      messages.append(ModelMessageBridge(message: message))
   }

   // insert messages and update data source
   self.collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths)
   self.JSQmessages.insert(messages, atIndex: 0) //error here
```

The two arrays have the same type, so I don't understand why it is not working...

Comment: with the `insert` method, you can only insert **one** element, not an array of elements.

Comment: @DánielNagy I actually based my code on this [link](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/781) and it looks like they are using an array into insert, doesn't it? And if not any idea how I could prepend an entire array?

Comment: @KaliAney Have a look at the `splice` method. You could also just use `self.JSQmessages = messages + self.JSQmessages`.

Comment: @KaliAney yes, it looks like, but there is no built in method for arrays like that one, you can check the documentation: http://swiftdoc.org/type/Array/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `splice` to insert new elements at a given index:

```
self.JSQmessages.splice(messages, atIndex: 0)
```

Also, you can greatly simplify your code with `map`:

```
self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
    let indexPaths = (0..<history.count).map {
        NSIndexPath(forItem: $0, inSection: 0)
    }

    let messages = history.map {
        ModelMessageBridge(message: $0)
    }

    self.JSQmessages.splice(messages, atIndex: 0)
    self.collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths)
```